# '[UITabBar appearance] setTitle' - Doesn't work in Xcode 5, iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar, uiappearance, ios7, xcode5

Xcode 5 is not even familiar with `setTitle` to `UITabBar`, the error is:

> No visible @interface for 'UITabBar' declares the selector 'setTitle:

Looking for `UITabBar` in: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/ doesn't show any changes in edition.
Whats going on here?

**EDIT:**

Original code is:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"home", nil)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: UITabBar or UINavigationBar?

Comment: Why do you want to set title of UITabBar from appearance class? Doesn't make sense. Btw, as far as I know UITabBar never ever had setTitle from appearance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pre-release software that is under NDA.

Comment: See my edited question. How should I set the title if not thru appearance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UITabBar` does not allow setting the title via `UIAppearance`. In general, no UI elements allow setting a title in this way. As a rule, UIAppearance is only for managing the styling of your application, not the content. See [this list](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521) for reference.

Comment: Show the exact code you are using to successfully set the title in iOS 6.

Comment: This is how your code works for me (Xcode 4.6.3 + iOS 6 SDK): `2013-07-02 14:38:32.716 redacted[47548:c07] -[_UIAppearance setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9658270`

Comment: Strange since it works well for me...

Comment: It should not work. A UITabBar doesn't even have a title. If I had to make a guess I would say that code is never called. Put a NSLog in the init method to verify that it is indeed called.

Comment: The thing is, it also work with a friend of mine at work with Xcode 4.6.3 with iOS 6.1 and still no issues.

Comment: OK, will try in a few minutes.

Comment: It does not work. Put a breakpoint in it. Your init method is never called. It's just that the compiler doesn't throw an error because `appearance` returns id on iOS 6 SDK, which makes all selectors valid during compile time. On iOS7 `appearance` returns instancetype, and the compiler knows that `setTitle:` is not a valid selector for a UITabBar.

Comment: OK, I see now you're right.